# Algebraic tori over function fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be any field of characteristic zero, and $K$ be a finitely generated field extension of $k$ with transcendence degree 1 (i.e. a function field of one variable).

Is it true that every 1-dimensional algebraic torus over $K$ is either $K^*$, or $SO(2,K)$? And what is the reference?

Comment: A naive approach : you can classify the curves $C_f = \{ (t,u) \in K^2, f(t,u)=1\}$ where $f \in K[t,u]$ splits in two linear factors in $\overline{K}[t,u]$, so the coefficients of the linear factors are in $K $ or in a quadratic extension $K(\sqrt{\alpha})$.